# Django - save user in another table

Tags: django, database, python-2.7, authentication

Is there a way to save my user registration in another table from the database?

I don't want to mix AdminUsers with CommonUsers (All the tutorials I've seen, they save the registration inside auth_user)

The reasons:

- CommonUsers have different columns and informations
- CommonUsers can upload content
- AdminUsers verify the content uploaded by the CommonUsers and make sure there is nothing inappropriate

What do I need to use? models? modelform? forms?

Answer (score -1):

The best solution for you is to subclass the `User` model and add the extra columns you need for your `CommonUsers`.  Your code will probably end up looking something like this:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import models
from django.db.models import *

class CommonUser(models.User):
    custom_field1 = CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    custom_field2 = CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

[Link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: wouldn't that give me an error? with the requiered fill (not null) for example: my AdminUser requires birthdate and cannot be null, but when the CommonUser register the birthdate is not asked, So what happen if the registration is valid, the birthdate filed for commonUser gets a default value?

Comment: You clearly to subclass `auth_user` for your AdminUser, as well, so that AdminUser and CommonUser are sibling classes, not parent and child. How did you add the birthdate field to your AdminUser?  Alternatively, you can stipulate a default value for those fields, like birthdate, that are only required by AdminUser.  But the first solution I offered is definitely the more correct way to do it.